# Linux on Macbook, dual-boot, without rEFind

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, dual-boot, bootable-disk

Is it possible to install a Linux distribution on a Macbook Pro partition and do a dual boot, without installing rEFind.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: The introduction of Ubuntu 18 has made these instructions obsolete. In other words, the Ubuntu 18 installer will automatically create files in the proper locations for Ubuntu to appear in the Startup Manager.

You can still employ step 7, if you want an Ubuntu icon to appear in the Startup Manager.

> Note: These instructions are for Mac models with 64 bit EFI firmware. In other words, if your Mac has Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8) or a newer version OS X (macOS) installed, then you can use these instructions.

Instead of using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), you can use the Startup Manager to boot most Linux distributions. The Startup Manager is contained in the the firmware that is already installed in your Mac. After installing a Linux distribution, you will need to move a few files around in order for the Startup Manager to recognize and boot the Linux distribution.

Most Linux distributions install grub and other files in the first EFI System partition on a Mac computer. Normally, this is the first partition on a Mac computer. The process of making a Linux distribution appear on the Startup Manager is a fairly trivial. The steps are given below for the Ubuntu Linux distribution. If you wish to install a different Linux distribution, post a command and I will verify if these instructions will work.

1. Install Ubuntu.
2. When finished, restart and hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key to
   invoke the Startup Manager. Select to boot from the OS X (or MacOS)
   volume.
3. Open a Terminal application window.
4. Mount the EFI System partition by entering the command given
   below.

   ```
   diskutil mount disk0s1
   ```
5. Create a folder named `Boot` in the folder `/Volumes/EFI/EFI`. You
   can use the Finder application or enter the command given below.

   ```
   mkdir /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot
   ```
6. Copy the file `grubx64.efi` from the folder
   `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu` to the folder `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot`.
   Next, rename this file `bootx64.efi`. This step can be accomplished
   by using the the Finder application or by entering the command given
   below.

   ```
   cp /Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
   ```
7. (Optional) Download a collection of icons from the sourceforge web
   site [Mac icns](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/). Use the Finder application to open the
   downloaded file `mac-icns.dmg`, then enter the command below to copy
   the Ubuntu icon file `os_ubuntu.icns` to the EFI System partition.

   ```
   cp /Volumes/mac-icns/os_ubuntu.icns /Volumes/EFI/.VolumeIcon.icns
   ```

   This will add the following Ubuntu icon to the Startup Menu.

   [image: os_ubuntu.png]

   > Note: When finished, you can use the Finder application to eject the `mac-icns` volume.
8. Use the Finder application or enter the command below to unmount
   the EFI System partition labeled `EFI`.

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk0s1
   ```

Comment: Thanks, and i can‘t do anything to my main system if I put it on a second partition?

Comment: Usually, you need to add at least 2 new partition when installing Linux. I could better answer if I knew which of Linux distribution you wish to install. I also need to know if you require encryption or a LVM. (a LVM is Linux's version of Apple's APFS.)

Comment: The LVM I don‘t know, but I was thinking about installing Debian, Arch or Fedora.

Comment: If you do not have a lot of experience with Linux, then I would suggest installing a free copy of VirtualBox. You can then download and install Linux distributions in virtual machines. This protects from any possibility of a Linux installation corrupting your computer. When done experimenting, just delete the virtual machine. Once you decide which Linux you want and you have had enough practice installing, you can try a dual boot of macOS and Linux.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I would like to use the startup manager and an encrypted LVM (using Pop_OS which does encrypt by default), do you have a blog post or something on how that would be done?

Comment: @Memphis: My answer involves the GRUB files that are part of an Ubuntu installation. I do not believe any of these files reside in the LVM and are therefore not encrypted. Also, read my updated answer.

Comment: Will this word with ubuntu-budgie-18.04.3?