# Linux on Mac, dual-boot without rEFind EFI issues

Tags: macos, unix, dual-boot, efi, mojave

So I followed the instructions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/318098/linux-on-macbook-dual-boot-without-refind/318107#318107?newreg=d15b0fc54b8f4417aa2cd98dd240087c)

This actually worked great. I was able to install ubuntu and the dual boot is working, however, in my startup window I have a dummy Windows option that boots to nothing. I did have bootcamp installed previously but have since wiped my drive clean to install Mojave. The windows option was not there until after I installed ubuntu. 
This is of course only a minor inconvenience but I figured I could use the opportunity to learn more about EFI. If anyone knows how to remove the Windows option, I would greatly appreciate it.